# setSelected работает в onLongClick() но не работает в bindView()

Tags: android, listview

Реализую [CAB](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB), ListView берет данные из БД. Когда скроллю ListView или поворачиваю экран, то фон ранее выбранных записей сбрасывается на дефолтный.

Холдер, который использую, чтобы сохранить статус (selected/not selected) и потом восстановить в `bindView`:

```
private static class ViewInfo {
    boolean selected;
}
```

bindView:

```
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        view.setOnLongClickListener(mOnLongClickListener);
        Object tag = view.getTag();
        if (tag != null) {
            ViewInfo info = (ViewInfo) view.getTag();
            view.setSelected(info.selected);
        } else {
            view.setTag(new ViewInfo());
        }

        // Load data from the database here
    }
```

OnLongClickListener:

```
mOnLongClickListener = new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        ViewInfo viewInfo = (ViewInfo) v.getTag();
        v.setSelected(viewInfo.selected = !viewInfo.selected);
        return true;
    }
};
```

ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/filtering_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoiceModal"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
```

Фон элемента списка ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/background_light" android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

Не понимаю, почему `setSelected` вызывается в `bindView`, значения true берутся из холдера, но сам фон не меняется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось запоминать выделенные записи без `setSelected`.

Изначально элемент списка не имеет фона, он ставится программно (в зависимости от состояния: выделено или нет).

Элемент списка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp" >
    <!-- text views, image views, etc. -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

ListView.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/filtering_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

OtItemLongClickListener. Сохраняю выделенные записи в хэш-таблицу, потому что она [обеспечивает O(1) для get, put, remove.](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)

```
mFilteringListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (mAdapter.mSelectedIds.get(id) == null || !mAdapter.mSelectedIds.get(id)) {
            mAdapter.mSelectedIds.put(id, true);
            view.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.highlighted_item));
        } else {
            /*
             * I don't put a false because there is no reason to store unselected items.
             * If the user selects and unselects items much, the hash table will grow
             * rapidly
             * 
             * Maksim Dmitriev
             * May 21, 2015
             */
            mAdapter.mSelectedIds.remove(id);
            view.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Адаптер ListView, в bindView элементам списка ставится фон:

```
private static class ListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    final Context mContext;
    LongSparseArray<Boolean> mSelectedIds = new LongSparseArray<Boolean>();

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        long id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Columns._ID));
        if (mSelectedIds.get(id) == null || !mSelectedIds.get(id)) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.highlighted_item));
        }
        // fill the other text views, image views, etc.
    }
}
```